# Definition of uniform equicontinuity of a family of mappings between uniform spaces

Tags: general-topology

From [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equicontinuity#Equicontinuity_in_topological_spaces)

> A set $A$ of **continuous** functions between two uniform spaces $X$ and
>   $Y$ is uniformly equicontinuous if for every element $W$ of the
>   uniformity on $Y$, **the set $\{ (u,v) ∈ X × X: \forall f ∈ A.
>  (f(u),f(v)) ∈ W \}$ is a member of the uniformity on $X$**.

1. I was wondering if it is equivalent to

   > A set $A$ of continuous functions between two uniform spaces $X$ and
   >   $Y$ is uniformly equicontinuous if for every element $W$ of the
   >   uniformity on $Y$, **there  is a member $V$ of the uniformity on $X$ such that $\forall (u,v) ∈ V, \forall f ∈ A.  (f(u),f(v)) ∈ W $**.

   This is because in [the special case when the uniform spaces are
   metric spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equicontinuity#Definition), for a family $F$ of continuous functions between two
   metric spaces:

   > The family $F$ is uniformly equicontinuous if for every $ε > 0$, there
   >   exists a $δ > 0$ such that $d(f(x_1), f(x_2)) < ε$ for all $f ∈ F$ and
   >   all $x_1, x_2 ∈ X$ such that $d(x_1, x_2) < δ$.

   Also this is because I think that the relation between equicontinuity and uniform equicontinuity should be similar to the relation between continuity and [uniform continuity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_continuity#Generalization_to_uniform_spaces).
2. Does the definition require the set of functions to be **continuous**?
   Doesn't the definition itself, when without requiring continuity, imply uniform continuity and therefore
   continuity?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, the two are equivalent. This follows from clause (2) of [this definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_structure#Entourage_definition) of a uniformity. Let $U=\{\langle u,v\rangle\in X\times X:\forall f\in A(\langle f(u),f(v)\rangle\in W\}$. If $U$ belongs to the uniformity on $X$, then $U$ itself is a member of the uniformity on $X$ such that for each $\langle u,v\rangle\in U$, $\langle f(u),f(v)\rangle\in W$. Conversely, if there is a member $V$ of the uniformity on $X$ such that for each $\langle u,v\rangle\in V$, $\langle f(u),f(v)\rangle\in W$, then $U\supseteq V$, so $U$ is in the uniformity on $X$.
2. Yes, uniform equicontinuity of a family of functions implies that the functions are uniformly continuous. It is not necessary in the definition to specify that the members of $A$ are continuous, but it does no real harm.